# How to allocate memory using this malloc statement?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, allocation

I have this method that reads a file. A matrix to be more specific where the first two numbers are the rows and the columns. However when i try to allocate the memory using malloc and using the rows and columns the application crash.

The code I'm using is this one:

```
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h
#include stdlib.h

float * readFile(char* nombre, int*renglones, int*columnas){
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(nombre,"r");

fscanf(fp,"%d",&renglones);

printf("el numero de renglones es %d\n",renglones);

fscanf(fp,"%d",&columnas);

printf("number of rows %d\n",columnas);
float value;

fscanf(fp,"%f",&value);
printf("el numero de columnas es %f\n",value);
fscanf(fp,"%f",&value);
printf("el numero de columnas es %f\n",value);
printf("no llegue a malloc");
float * res = malloc(*renglones**columnas*sizeof(float)); //memory reservation and the line that breaks the program 
printf("after malloc");



fclose(fp);
return 0;

}
```

I know that the includes are between <>

The final code is this one with the includes: stdio.h and stdlib.h

```
  float * readFile(char* nombre, int*renglones, int*columnas){
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(nombre,"r");
fscanf(fp,"%d",renglones);
printf("el numero de renglones es %d\n",renglones);
fscanf(fp,"%d",columnas);
printf("el numero de columnas es %d\n",columnas);
float value;
float * res = (float*)malloc(*renglones**columnas*sizeof(float)); //Reserva de memoria
printf("llegue a malloc\n");
int i;
for(i=0;i<*renglones**columnas;i++){
        fscanf(fp, "%f",&value);
        res[i]=value;
        printf("dato %f\n",value);
}
printf("%d",i);
fclose(fp);
return res;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is `rows` and `columns`??

Comment: i have change to "columnas" and "renglones" .

Comment: Also in this way float* res = (float*)malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(float)); but it doesnt work

Comment: Using `(*renglones)*(*columnas)*sizeof…` changes things?

Comment: @Stefano Sanfilippo: Why would it?

Comment: The obvious and only relevant question is: *what is the actual number* that you're passing to malloc?  The first thing you should do is calculate and print that number right before the malloc call to see what you're passing.  If you're trying to do something like allocate a negative number, or allocate 50 GB, then failure is entirely expected.

Comment: @Haroogan In theory they are equally correct, in practice an extra `*` could slip somewhere and make everyhing crash over silly segmentation faults. Posted as a comment as this obviously is not the answer, anyway....

Comment: A good compiler should have issued a lot of diagnostics about your code, and that should have told you that you have indirection errors by misinterpreting your function arguments. Always compile with `-Wall` or equivalent compiler flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you do:

```
...
fscanf(fp,"%d",&renglones);
...
fscanf(fp,"%d",&columnas);
...
```

As a result, those 2 numbers (that you read from file) become pointers to `renglones` and `columnas` which you further dereference to calculate the size for `malloc`. For instance, if you read numbers `16` and `32`, then `renglones` points to `0x00000010` and `columnas` points to `0x00000020`. However, these memory cells obviously contain random garbage (from the point of view of your task), i.e. they probably contain arbitrarily huge numbers which when multiplied together give even bigger number, and `malloc` simply cannot allocate that much amount of memory, which ultimately results in crash.

Instead it should be:

```
...
fscanf(fp,"%d",renglones);
...
fscanf(fp,"%d",columnas);
...
```

since both `renglones` and `columnas` are pointers already. This way you would really fill the two `int` variables to which `renglones` and `columnas` point to, and get the expected behavior.